# Overwriting previous iterations of if statement in R

Tags: r, algorithm, if-statement, genetic

I am VERY new to R and am having a very difficult time getting an answer to this, so I finally caved to post - so apologies ahead of time.

I am using a genetic algorithm to optimize the shape of an object, and want to gather the intermediate steps for prototyping. The package I am using genalg, allows a monitor function to track the data which I can print just fine. But I'd like to stash it in a data frame for other uses and keep watching it overwrite the other iterations. Here's my code for the monitor function:

```
    monitor <- function(obj){

    #Make empty data frame in which to store data
    resultlist <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 200, ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE))

    #If statement evaluating each iteration of algorithm
    if (obj$iter > 0){

    #Put results into list corresponding to number of iteration
    resultlist[,obj$iter] <- obj$population[which.min(obj$best),]}

    #Make data frame available at global level for prototyping, output, etc.
    resultlistOutput <<- resultlist}
```

I know this works in a for loop with no issues based on searches, so I must be doing something wrong or the if syntax is not capable of this?

Sincere thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being not sure what error you are getting, I am guessing you are getting only the result from last iteration. This is happening because you are overwriting your global dataframe in each call to `monitor` function. You should first initialize `resultlistOutput <<- data.frame()` this way and then do this:

```
monitor <- function(obj){

#Make empty data frame in which to store data
resultlist <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 200, ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE))

#If statement evaluating each iteration of algorithm
if (obj$iter > 0){

#Put results into list corresponding to number of iteration
resultlist[,obj$iter] <- obj$population[which.min(obj$best),]}

#Make data frame available at global level for prototyping, output, etc.
# append the dataframe to the old result
resultlistOutput <<- rbind(resultlistOutput , resultlist)
}
```

Comment: `rbind`ing an accumulating `data.frame` on every iteration is going to get slow real quick. I think the bigger issue is believing that you can inspect an object while the algorithm is running. Writing a small piece of informative information to the console might be a better approach.

Comment: Yup. I know. Specially with genetic algorithm you may need to run the optimizations for 200 epochs and each time your candidate population set gets bigger and bigger, appending to the dataframe is surely not a good idea. Showed it that way only because the OP asked for it. I should have added a piece of advice for not doing it in the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew I was missing something, and was able to adjust to get the results I want. 

Just to clarify, I was not inspecting during the runs, just wanted to see that I was getting expected results for now (was quashing an earlier bug that made it so my evaluation function was not being adhered to).

But to that point, I know there must be more elegant ways to achieve this within the monitor function. If you have time, would you mind outlining an alternative at a high level?

Thanks again!